# Is it possible to create a new text field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about adding new text box in the post content type.I found  one module for this "custom fields".Other than that is it possible to create it as a module?

Answer (score 0):

custom fields where introduced to store those kind of informations. but they doesn't look good.

thats why wp hackers introduced metaboxes  - they are based on custom fields (data are stored in same way) but kan look better. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

my favorite class for fast creating metaboxes is http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

Answer (score 0):

i would go for Wordpress Multiple Content Blocks plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/

you can have different text areas for different page templates

Answer (score -1):

I use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for this, it's the best plugin I've come across.